# Compare date part of datetime column with NamedQuery

Tags: datetime, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, java-ee-7

I have a table containing entries with date and time. I try to create a NamedQuery which only compares the date part.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Vote.findForDate", query = "SELECT v FROM Vote v WHERE v.createdAt = :date")
...
createNamedQuery("Vote.findForDate").setParameter("date", date, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

But it seems that it always tries to compare the whole datetime.

Is there no way without using `date()` function in SQL?
I try to be independent from the database. For example h2 has no `date()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is the usage of date as column type and reduce the information.

```
  @Column(name = "voteDate")
  @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date voteDate;
```